# Jquery change() method repeat on click(x+2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-plugins

I have write some code in JS for my jquery plugin.. During writing a script I followed by strange problem that Jquery method `change()` continue repeating x+2 times(means if i click first time on element this work nice and in chrome console i see  one output but when i click second time on same element in console i watch three output and if i click third time in console i watch 5 times  ).

First Click:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ7g5.png.

second Click : https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8zbD.png

I pasted small piece of my code in jsbin.com/xiyala/edit?html,js,console,output there you can watch also in console.

Paste here in also same code in snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var cont = $("<div class='txtbrCont tetb_1  _txb01 sng_01'></div>");
    var FS = $("<select id='slcvluimp' class = 'a2sdf1 sdf45a1 srlize tetb_5  _txb05 sng_05 cmncls'>" +
      "<option value='0op'>Font Size</option>" +
      "<option value='6pt'>6pt</option>" +
      "<option value='8pt'>8pt</option>" +
      "<option value='10pt'>10pt</option>" +
      "<option value='12pt'>12pt</option>" +
      "<option value='16pt'>16pt</option>" +
      "<option value='18pt'>18pt</option>" +
      "<option value='24pt'>24pt</option>" +
      "</select>");
    cont.append(FS);
    $("#appendTome").append(cont);
cont.on("click", function(e) {
  var value1 = "1";
  switch (value1) {
    case ("1"):
      $(".tetb_5").on("change", function() {
        getSelectOptionValue();
      });
    break;   
    case ("2"):
      console.log("hello world");
    break;
    default:
  }
});
function getSelectOptionValue() {
  var one = null;
  one = $("._txb05" + " option:selected").text();
  console.log(one);
  return one;
}

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="appendTome"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post your code **here** as part of your question.

Comment: ok updated my code !!

Comment: You're setting up the "change" event handler *inside* the "click" handler. That means you set up a new copy of that handler each time the "click" handler is called (because `value1` is always `"1"`).  With jQuery, assigning a handler with `.on()` does not remove other handlers for the event; it just adds another one, and all the ones that have been added are called when a "change" event happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 triggers in the following code:

```
cont.on("click", function(e) {
  var value1 = "1";
  switch (value1) {
    case ("1"):
      $(".tetb_5").on("change", function() {
        getSelectOptionValue();
      });
    break;   
    case ("2"):
      console.log("hello world");
    break;
    default:
  }
});
```

One on `cont` and one on `$(".tetb_5")`

If you try selecting it once and then using the arrow keys to change the selection it works because you're only activating the on `$(".tetb_5")`

You should just have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cont = $("<div class='txtbrCont tetb_1  _txb01 sng_01'></div>");
    var FS = $("<select id='slcvluimp' class = 'a2sdf1 sdf45a1 srlize tetb_5  _txb05 sng_05 cmncls'>" +
      "<option value='0op'>Font Size</option>" +
      "<option value='6pt'>6pt</option>" +
      "<option value='8pt'>8pt</option>" +
      "<option value='10pt'>10pt</option>" +
      "<option value='12pt'>12pt</option>" +
      "<option value='16pt'>16pt</option>" +
      "<option value='18pt'>18pt</option>" +
      "<option value='24pt'>24pt</option>" +
      "</select>");
    cont.append(FS);
    $("#appendTome").append(cont);
      $(".tetb_5").on("change", function() {
        getSelectOptionValue();
      });
});

function getSelectOptionValue() {
  var one = $("._txb05" + " option:selected").text();
  console.log(one);
  return one;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never put event inside another because it will be attached every time you the first one excecuted, and that what caused the problem for your :

```
cont.on("click", function(e) { <-- First Event
  var value1 = "1";
  switch (value1) {
    case ("1"):
      $(".tetb_5").on("change", function() { <-- Second Event inside it
        getSelectOptionValue();
      });
    break;   
    case ("2"):
      console.log("hello world");
    break;
    default:
  }
});
```

Assign the `change` event handler outside the code for the `click` event handler like @Pointy mentioned in comment below :

```
$(".tetb_5").on("change", function() {
    getSelectOptionValue();
});

cont.on("click", function(e) {
  var value1 = "1";
  switch (value1) {
    case ("1"):
       //Not sure what you want to do here
    break;   
    case ("2"):
      console.log("hello world");
    break;
    default:
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Hex0R assign the "change" event handler *outside* the code for the "click" event handler.

Comment: It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking, you could post another question that clarify your specific problem and add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: No i can't see the same problem in your jsbin. the console print the correct  result.